# How do I in replace "&" with "%20" in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I recently created a code to send an order to WhatsApp but I'm running into trouble trying to make the code send a message.

[image: URL preview]

The issue is that before each input the message gets an `&` and I need to replace it with `%20` in order for it to work with WhatsApp.

I've tried to change the code and nothing seems to work.

My actual code is:

```html
<form action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?" method="GET" target="_blank" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="56987955586" />
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="" />
    <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0; display: grid; grid-gap: 10px;">
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Producto 1:</span>
            <input type="number" name="producto1" min="0" value="0" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 70px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
        </li>
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Producto 2:</span>

            <input type="number" name="producto2" min="0" value="0" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 70px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" style="background-color: #00c853; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 40px; border: none; padding: 15px 30px; margin: 20px auto; display: block; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">
        Enviar Pedido por WhatsApp
    </button>
</form>
<style>
@media (min-width: 501px) {
    ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
    ul {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: The %20 is a space character.  Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, I need to replace the "&" to "%20" or the text doesn't show up on the whatsapp message. 

I know the "%20" is a space character . 

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Your form appears to be working exactly as intended. If this isn't working, how _should_ it work instead?

Comment: When I hit the submit button, the link I'm getting is: 

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=56987955586&text=&producto1=0&producto2=0

The issue is basically the "&producto1=0&producto2=0"

I'd like to replace it to "%20producto1=0%20producto2=0"

Comment: And do what with them? Put them into the `text` parameter?

Comment: If you want to attach those `producto[N]` values to the message, you must insert them into the message body *before* you built the query string.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, guys. 
But I'm not managing to solve the issue. 

I'm still getting the "&" symbol instead of an "%20" between each "producto[N]"  :(

Comment: At this point in time, you're just using a standard HTML form, with its standard behaviour, to submit the form values to an external URL.  You won't be able to manipulate the way that behaviour is occurring through straight HTML alone.  You'll need to look at using some javascript, which will be triggered by your "submit" button (which will actually just become an input button - not specifically a form-submitting button).  When that button is clicked, the javascript code will be able to extract the values from your inputs and build the necessary query string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed the *producto* values into the `text` parameter, you'll need some JS in order to do so.

First, replace the `name` attributes with `id` so they're not included in the form data and add a class to help identify them

```html
<input
  type="number"
  id="producto1"
  min="0"
  value="0"
  class="text-body"
/>
```

Then add a *submit* event listener to collect the values and insert them into the `text` input value

```html
<form id="whatsapp-form" ...>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("whatsapp-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.target.querySelector("input[name=text]").value = Array.from(
    e.target.querySelectorAll(".text-body"),
    ({ id, value }) => `${id}=${value}`
  ).join(" ");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you do want to attach those input *producto[N]* values to the message body. In order to get that, you must follow these steps:

1. [Stop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) form submit.
2. Get the *producto[N]* values.
3. Set those values as the message body.
4. [Build the query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).
5. [Build the URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).
6. [Set URL's query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search).
7. [Send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) the message.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
      phone = form.phone.value;

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    //1. Stop form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //2. Get the productos values
    const values = [...form.querySelectorAll("[name^=producto]")].map(elem => elem.previousElementSibling.textContent + elem.value);
        
    //3. Set those values as the message body
    const text = `Here are the products: ${values.join(", ")}`;
        
    //4. Build the query string
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams({phone, text});
        
    //5. Build the URL
    const url = new URL(form.action);

    //6. Set URL's query string
    url.search = queryString;
        
    //7. Send the message (new tab)
    window.open(url);

    //Optional: location = url; (same tab)
}, false);
```

```css
@media (min-width: 501px) {
    ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
    ul {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?" method="GET" target="_blank" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="56987955586" />
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="" />
    <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0; display: grid; grid-gap: 10px;">
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Producto 1:</span>
            <input type="number" name="producto1" min="0" value="0" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 70px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
        </li>
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Producto 2:</span>
            <input type="number" name="producto2" min="0" value="0" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 70px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" style="background-color: #00c853; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 40px; border: none; padding: 15px 30px; margin: 20px auto; display: block; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">
        Enviar Pedido por WhatsApp
    </button>
</form>
```

---

Thanks [Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577492/how-do-i-in-replace-with-20-in-html/76577613#comment135016719_76577613) for the API URL suggest.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Good one! I forgot that API. Editing now...

Comment: Just wondering why you changed the text format. OP seems to want a space delimited list of `productoN=value`

Comment: @Philisonstrike Because the screenshot shows more than a couple, so I thought that somewhere in the document there's an *input add* button or maybe there are more inputs.

Comment: What I mean is that yours is prefixed with _"Here are the products:"_ and each pair is comma separate and uses the `<span>` text instead of the `<input>` name

Comment: @Philisonstrike Just for a better looking result. I prefer a **Producto 1: 5** than a  **producto1 5**.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon My bad; for a minute I was confused with its PHP equivalent function (ironically I oftenly use the `substring` method, but that briefly confusion got me). And about the URL query string... yes, you're right. I thought it was necessary to take that `?` out of the `form.action` value, but I just tried your suggest and it works. Thanks, once again.